# Formating pendrive in Ubuntu

Tags: usb-flash-drive, ubuntu-12.04, formatting

The pendrive contains a virus and I'm unable to format it due to write protection and I haven't enabled it. I searched the Internet to format it from terminal but it always failed with write protection error. I've tried diskpart and GParted Partition Manager.

I'm also new to Ubuntu/Linux and just began to learn computer so please be general. Please help me out to format my pendrive either on Windows or Ubuntu.

Comment: Make sure the pendrive is unmounted. Right-click its icon in the launcher on the left and choose *Unmount*. Then try the standard formatting procedure with GParted just as you have already tried.

Comment: not working :( . i need to format it either in windows or Ubuntu it doesn't matter

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it's a wrong place to put up this question [AskUbuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/)

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>f2</kbd>

type 'gnome-disks'

Here you can see your flash drive, select that from left side,
on right side, right click and select to 'format' option

make sure to check filesystem is `NTFS` or `FAT32`, so it will be accessible from Windows OSs too.

Comment: not working :(  i just want to format it in windows or ubuntu doesnt matter just want to reuse my usb

Comment: are you sure pendrive is working fine on other systems